# How to display the selected menu item in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I want to selected menu to get displayed and saved when the user comes back later. my current code just displays the selected item, but not getting saved when I close the sheet and comes back.

---

```
  @State var selectedAge: Int = .zero
  
  var body: some View {
    Menu {
      ForEach(myViewModel.MyModel.selectAge.indices, id: \.self) { indice in
        Button(action: {
          selectedAge = indice
        }) {
          if selectedAge == indice {
            Text("\(myViewModel.MyModel.selectAge[indice])")
          }
          else {
            Text("")
          }
        }
      }
    } label: {
      Text("\(myViewModel.MyModel.selectAge[selectedAge])")
    }
  }
```

This code from my Model

```
var selectedAge: [String] = ["12", "15", "18", "21", "24"]
```

Please guide me to solve this issue.

Comment: You can basically store the selectedAge in [UserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults).

Comment: yes, I've already implemented user defaults and its working for other steppers, pickers widgets. but its not working only for menu.

Comment: Could you please edit your question with UserDefaults version and we can see what you are doing wrong, because all you need is persistence.

Comment: what I think is, because of the @state,  it getting replaced to the .zero (first index ["12"]) when user close and open again. could that be the reason?

Comment: Exactly, that's what I am saying..You are not persisting any selectedAge so when you open that Menu you see the first item of selectedAge array. You can also use [@AppStorage](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/appstorage).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this code to solve my issue.

```swift
Menu {
    ForEach(myViewModel.myModel.selectAge, id: \.self) { index in
        Button {
            myViewModel.myModel.selectAge = "\(index)"
        } {
            if myViewModel.myModel.selectedAge == index {
                Label("\(index)", systemImage: "checkmark")
            } else {
                Text("\(index)")
            }
        }
    }
} label: {
    Text("\(myViewModel.myModel.selectedAge)")
}
```

and this is insert in my model

```
var selectedAge = "12"
var selectedAge: [String] = ["12", "15", "18", "21", "24"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

// selectedAge1 array list replace with your data model list...

```
import Combine

class MenuAgeSettings: ObservableObject {
    @Published var selectedAge: String {
        didSet {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(selectedAge, forKey: "selectedAge")
        }
    }
    
    init() {
        self.selectedAge = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "selectedAge") as? String ?? ""
    }
}

struct MenuView: View {
    var selectedAge1: [String] = ["12", "15", "18", "21","24"]
    
    @ObservedObject var menuSettings = MenuAgeSettings()
        
    var body: some View {
       Menu{
          ForEach(self.selectedAge1.indices, id: \.self){ indice in
              let text = self.selectedAge1[indice]
               Button(action : {
                   menuSettings.selectedAge = text
               }) {
                if menuSettings.selectedAge == text {
                      Label(text, systemImage: "checkmark")
                   } else {
                      Text(text)
                   }
               }
           }
        } label: {
            if menuSettings.selectedAge.isEmpty {
                Text(selectedAge1[.zero])
            } else {
                Text(menuSettings.selectedAge)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: its getting checked but when I close and open the screen again, its getting reseted to first index of the array